# Trying to make QuizMaker in C, but some steps are ignored with !X

Tags: arrays, c, char, c-strings

Basically I'm trying to make QuizMaker by asking user how many questions they want, then make a string of an array. I'm new to C, so I might be missing some little details. Please look at the screenshot of console which I included.

[image: Screen shot of my console]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096

int input(char *str, int n);

int main() {
    int a, i, length = 0;
    printf("How many questions do you want?\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    char *strarr[a]; 
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; //string holder
    
    while (getchar() != '\n'); //in case there is \n, flush it
        
    for(i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        printf("Question number #%d:\n", i + 1);
        length = input(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        //input method returns number of chars we've entered
        strarr[i] = malloc((length) * sizeof(char));
        //allocating memory for each pointers to array of chars
        strcpy(strarr[i], buffer);
        //copy the string you've just created to an array of strings
    }
    //printing results
    printf("_____________\n");
    for(i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", strarr[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int input(char *str, int n) {
    int ch, i = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (i < n)
            str[i++] = ch;
        str[i] = '\0';
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: The length that `input` return, does it include the null-terminator? If it doesn't, think about what happens when you attempt to call `strcpy` which will add the null-terminator to memory your program doesn't own.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks a lot, this solved my issue. Tbh I don't know how strcpy() function works internally, but I'll look into it. Cheers mate!

Comment: @erik258 Not always. And considering that `strncpy` might not always add the null-terminator is might lead to other problems.

Comment: If you have solution, please post it as an actual answer. Or delete this question if you think it is of no value for future visitors.

Comment: @erik258: [**never** use `strncpy`!](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems in the code:

- the test `if (i < n)` is not strict enough: you should stop storing characters to the destination array before it is full to save space for the null terminator.
- you must allocate one extra byte for the null terminator: `malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char))` or just `malloc(length + 1)` as `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.
- you should test for `EOF` in addition to `'\n'` in the reading loops.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096

int input(char *str, int n);

int main() {
    int a, c, i, length = 0;
    printf("How many questions do you want?\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1 || a <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char *strarr[a]; 
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; //string holder
    
    // flush the rest of the input line
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
        
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        printf("Question number #%d:\n", i + 1);
        //input method returns number of chars we've entered
        length = input(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        //allocating memory for each pointers to array of chars
        strarr[i] = malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (strarr[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "allocation error\n");
            a = i;
            break;
        }
        //copy the string you've just created to an array of strings
        strcpy(strarr[i], buffer);
    }
    //printing results
    printf("_____________\n");
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", strarr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int input(char *str, int n) {
    int ch, i = 0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
        if (i + 1 < n)
            str[i++] = ch;
    }
    if (i < n)
        str[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Also note that you can use `strdup()` to allocate and copy the string in a single call:

```
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        printf("Question number #%d:\n", i + 1);
        input(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        /* allocate a copy of the string */
        strarr[i] = strdup(buffer);
        if (strarr[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "allocation error\n");
            a = i;
            break;
        }
    }
```